# Using grid to create columns but doesnt display two columns

Tags: html, grid, tailwind-css

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
    <div>
      <label for="" class="text-jibuttonBlue flex items-center ml-2">Image style</label>
      <form class="flex flex-col" action="index.html" method="post">

      </form>
    </div>
      <div>
      <div class="relative w-272">
        <div data-id="menu-container"></div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label for="name" class="">
            <span class="text-jibuttonBlue">To be used for:</span>
            <div class="flex items-center border-b border-jiborderGrey py-2 relative">
              <!--
            <div class="rounded-full py px-2 border-jibuttonBlue bg-jinumberblue border text-sm mr-2">Etz Chaim</div>
            <div class="rounded-full py px-2 border-jibuttonBlue bg-jinumberblue border text-sm">Rimon</div>
            <div class="rounded-full py px-2 text-sm">+2</div>
            -->
              <img src="{{MEDIA_UI}}/search-24-px.svg" alt="" class="absolute right-10 top-25">
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <!--If error message is needed add class "border-r border-jierrorred and text-jierrorred for label"-->
        <div>
          <label for="" class="text-jibuttonBlue flex items-center ml-2">Suitable for age</label>
          <form class="flex flex-col" action="index.html" method="post"></form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am creating to columns but its not showing the divs in two columns. Any idea why its not working?
It was working before but stopped and I cant find the issue in the code. It is following exactly the same structure as the instructions. Using tailwind.css.

Comment: I've edited your code to a snippet and added tailwind.css. If you hit "Run code snippet" you can see two columns. Is this the desired output or how should it look like?

Comment: Seems like there was a cache issue that made it look wrong.
Thanks for adding tailwind.